# Puppet hiera not inheriting properly (Puppet version 4.3.2)

Tags: yaml, puppet, hierarchy, hiera, facter

My `/etc/puppetlabs/code` folder structure:

```
[vagrant@client code]$ pwd
/etc/puppetlabs/code
[vagrant@client code]$ tree
.
├── environments
│   ├── production
│   │   ├── environment.conf
│   │   ├── hieradata
│   │   ├── manifests
│   │   └── modules
│   └── test
│       ├── hieradata
│       ├── manifests
│       │   └── site.pp
│       └── modules
├── hieradata
│   ├── common.yaml
│   └── hostname
│       └── client.yaml
├── hiera.yaml
└── modules
```

Then, for my YAML files:

```
[vagrant@client code]$ cat hiera.yaml 
---
:backends:
  - yaml
:hierarchy:
  - "hostname/%{facts.hostname}"
  - "os/%{facts.osfamily}"
  - common
:yaml:
  :datadir: /etc/puppetlabs/code/hieradata
merge_behavior: deeper

[vagrant@client code]$ cat hieradata/common.yaml 
---
users:
  jill:
    uid: 1000
    home: '/home/jill'
  jack:
    uid: 1001
    home: '/home/jack'

[vagrant@client code]$ cat hieradata/hostname/client.yaml 
---
users:
  jill:
    home: '/homes/jill'
  jack:
    home: '/homes/jack'
  jane:
    uid : 999
    home: '/homes/jane'
```

Yet, when I run hiera, I get the following:

```
[vagrant@client code]$ hiera --hash users
{"jill"=>{"uid"=>1000, "home"=>"/home/jill"},
 "jack"=>{"uid"=>1001, "home"=>"/home/jack"}}
[vagrant@client code]$ hiera --hash users ::hostname=client
{"jill"=>{"uid"=>1000, "home"=>"/home/jill"},
 "jack"=>{"uid"=>1001, "home"=>"/home/jack"}}
```

My `hieradata/hostname/client.yaml` should be overriding the `common.yaml`, causing the `hiera` command to return something different when `::hostname=client` is handed in.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $facts hash is set by the puppet agent / apply and I don't expect it to be available when you try validating your settings by hiera command line.

You can either use `- "hostname/%{::hostname}"` in your hierarchy to get the expected results from your hiera cmd or consider using the puppet command line to verify your settings instead.

Comment: Hmm, this partially works, but not completely. It does inheirit, but for example `uid=1000` doesn't propogate to the "client" `[vagrant@client code]$ hiera --hash users ::hostname=client
{"jill"=>{"home"=>"/homes/jill"},
 "jack"=>{"home"=>"/homes/jack"},
 "jane"=>{"uid"=>999, "home"=>"/homes/jane"}}
[vagrant@client code]$ hiera --hash users 
{"jill"=>{"uid"=>1000, "home"=>"/home/jill"},
 "jack"=>{"uid"=>1001, "home"=>"/home/jack"}}`

Comment: ah yes! a colon is missing before merge_behaviour. should be `:merge_behavior: deeper`